# How to delete a facebook marketing lead form using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

According to the facebook documentation here [Deleting a Lead Form](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/create)
this is how you do it:
Send a `delete http` request to https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/formId?access_token=the_access_token.

However I get the error below when I try the above:

```
 {
"error": {
    "message": "(#210) This call requires a Page access token.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 210,
    "fbtrace_id": "ABC123/xyz"
 }
}
```

When I use a Page access token (as suggest by the error response) this is what I get:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#3) Subject must be on whitelist",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 3,
        "fbtrace_id": "IJK123/uvw"
    }
}
```

If it matters the accessToken initially used is the same token used to create the leadform.

How can I get this to work? What am I missing?